# How can i hide my module code (But not module functionalities) in react-native projects?

Tags: javascript, react-native, node-modules, react-native-ios

I am developing sample application in react-native. i am using Third-party module in react-native. But this same module will be useful in another projects also.So all Projects can access this module functionalities but not the code(what i mean to say is in other projects i won't allow them to see my module code). Is there any way to achieve this.

1. this is sample third party module in react-native : 
   https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip
2. The main aspect is not to show the code but access the methods.

Thanks in advance.